# AttributeError: 'PostDetailView' object has no attribute 'method

Tags: python, python-3.x, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I tried using dispatch() in my code but unfortunately ran into multiple errors I could not resolve. The last error was AttributeError: 'PostDetailView' object has no attribute 'method'.  I can't get existing comments to appear (I added some via the admin page) or the comment form.

**views.py**

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
        model = Post

    def dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs):
        post = get_object_or_404(Post)
        comments = post.comments.filter(active=True)
        new_comment = None

        if request.method == 'POST':
            comment_form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)
            if comment_form.is_valid():
                new_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
                new_comment.post = post
                new_comment.save()
            else:
                comment_form = CommentForm()
                return render(request, template_name, {'post': post,
                                           'comments': comments,
                                           'new_comment': new_comment,
                                          'comment_form': comment_form})
```

**forms.py**

```
from .models import Comment
from django import forms

class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('name', 'email', 'body')
```

**models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    content =  models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title 

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk':self.pk})


class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='comments')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    email = models.EmailField()
    body = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `self` as the first positional argument (before `request`) in your `dispatch` method definition.

The first argument passed to `dispatch()` is the view object, which you call `request`. That's why when you do `request.method` it's looking for the `method` attribute on the view object.